# Fibered product of stacks comes from a Lie groupoid

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, stacks, lie-groupoids, differentiable-stacks

I am adding some context here. I am reading [Introduction to Differentiable Stacks](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~gregory.ginot/papers/DiffStacksIGG2013.pdf) by Gregory Ginot.

In page no $7$, just before the remark $2.2$ he says the following.

> One shall be careful that fibre product of differentiable stacks is not necessarily a differentiable stack  (though it is a stack over $\text{Diff}$).

So, one question  we can think of is,

> when does a fibre product of differentiable stacks a differentiable stack?

This seems to be too difficult to answer. So, I look for a simpler question.

> When does $B\mathcal{G}\times_{B\mathcal{H}} B\mathcal{G}$ a differentiable stack where the fibre product is coming from a given morphism of stacks $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$.

---

Question in context of Lie groups is as follows.

Suppose $G,H$ be Lie groups and $F:BG\rightarrow BH$ be a map of stacks.

> When can we say that  the fibered product $BG\times_{BH}BG$ is a differentiable stack i.e., of the form $B\mathcal{K}$ for some Lie groupoid $\mathcal{K}$?

Assume that this  $F:BG\rightarrow BH$ is coming from a morphism of Lie groups $\theta:G\rightarrow H$.

Then, we can ask following question.

> When can we say that  the fibered product $BG\times_{BH}BG$ is a differentiable stack  coming from Lie group i.e., of the form $BK$ for some Lie group $K$?

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of $BG$ and $BH$ as *topological stacks*, whereby one can calculate a topological groupoid presenting the stack $BG\times_{BH} BG$, namely the following: the object space is the space underlying $H$ and the morphism space is $G\times H \times G$. The source map $s\colon G\times H \times G \to H$ is the projection on the middle factor; the target map $t\colon G\times H \times G \to H$ is $(g_1,h,g_2) \mapsto \theta(g_1)^{-1}h\,\theta(g_2)$. (The reason you can do this is because the Lie groupoids presenting the stacks $BG$ and $BH$ only have a single object, so the situation is rather special. For more general Lie groupoids it is a little more fiddly, but not too different.)

For the stack $BG\times_{BH} BG$ to be equivalent to one of the form $BK$ for some *topological* group $K$, the topological groupoid I just described must be *transitive*: every object should be isomorphic to every other object. That is, for every pair $h_1,h_2\in H$ there should be elements $g_1,g_2\in G$ such that $h_2 = \theta(g_1)^{-1}h_1\theta(g_2)$. If $\theta$ is surjective, then you can take $g_1 = e_G$ and $g_2$ any lift of $h_1^{-1}h_2$, so this is a sufficient condition (in the topological case).

Now if we go back to general $\theta$, but take the special case $h_1 = e_H$, then we require for any $h\in H$ that $h= \theta(g_1^{-1}g_2)$, so in fact $\theta$ surjective is a *necessary* condition. To figure out *which* group $K$ it is such that $BG\times_{BH} BG \simeq BK$—it is a priori well-defined up to isomorphism of topological groups—we need to consider the pairs $g_1,g_2$ such that $h = \theta(g_1)^{-1}h\theta(g_2)$ for some chosen $h\in H$. We might as well take $h=e_H$, so that we want pairs $g_1,g_2 \in G$ such that $e_H = \theta(g_1^{-1}g_2)$, or in other words, such that $\theta(g_1) = \theta(g_2)$. The space of such pairs is just $G\times_H G$, which is a topological subgroup of $G\times G$, and so $K=G\times_H G$.

(In fact $G\times \ker \theta \to G\times_H G$, $(g,k) \mapsto (g,gk)$ is a homeomorphism, but only a topological group isomorphism if $\ker \theta \lt G$ is central subgroup.)

---

Now if we want to do this in *Lie groups*, then everything works, except that we need $K = G\times_H G$ to be a *sub-Lie-group* of $G\times G$, and this is so if $\theta$ is a submersion. But a surjective map of (finite-dimensional) Lie groups is automatically a submersion. Thus $G\to H$ is a surjective submersion, and hence a locally trivial bundle (this follows from using charts derived from the exponential map and the surjective map of the associated Lie algebras).

If we don't care about $BG\times_{BH} BG \simeq BK$ for some $K$, then $\theta$ being a submersion should be enough to make $G\times H \times G \rightrightarrows H$ a Lie groupoid (the only hard part is to show that $(g_1,h,g_2) \mapsto \theta(g_1)^{-1}h\,\theta(g_2)$ is a submersion).

Even in the special case analysed above, we don't know that $K$ is a central subgroup, or that $G\twoheadrightarrow H$ is a central extension, but that's not necessary for your question. So we find ourselves in the situation Dmitri gave in greater generality: $(G\rightrightarrows \ast) \to (H \rightrightarrows \ast)$ is a submersion on arrows and object components.

---

**Added**  There was a small unimportant lie in what I wrote: it is not sufficient in the topological case for $\theta$ to be just surjective, to have an equivalence of stacks $BG \times_{BH} BG \simeq BK$. Namely, it is not true that the groupoid that I described being transitive is enough. One must have a certain map to have local sections, and this boils down to requiring that $\theta$ have local sections. In the smooth case we ask that this map is a surjective *submersion*, but this follows from $\theta$ just being surjective, as this already implies it is a submersion.

Comment: About Lie groups, yes we need $G\times_H G$ to be a Lie subgroup of $G\times G$.. You can see edit version 1 https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/320210/1 I assumed it is a Lie subgroup... Thanks. I will respond after spending some time on this. :)

Comment: I am still trying to guesss how you thought of the Lie groupoid $G\times H\times G\rightrightarrows H$... Can you please tell me how did this occur suddenly?

Comment: It is the weak pullback of $(G\rightrightarrows \ast) \to (H \rightrightarrows \ast)$ along itself. See Definition 1.15 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04209.pdf

Comment: :) I was thinking this is similar to **pull back of a Lie groupoid** $\mathcal{G}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{G}_0$ along a smooth map $J:M\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ which can be found in page no 6 section $2.2$ in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511696.pdf... There is also a notion of fibre product of $\mathcal{H}\times_{\mathcal{G}}\mathcal{K}$ **given two morphism of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{K}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$** which can be found in page $5$ section $2.3$ named Fibered products in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203100.pdf

Comment: Here $\mathcal{H}\times_{\mathcal{G}}\mathcal{K}$ given that you have morphism of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{K}$.... To be precise both morphisms of Lie groupoids for you is same thing and that is $\{G\rightrightarrows *\}\rightarrow \{H\rightrightarrows *\}$... Ok.. Thank you :) There is also an explanation in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203100.pdf  says **when** $\mathcal{H}\times_{\mathcal{G}}\mathcal{K}$ is **a Lie groupoid**.. That looks same thing as what you said. Thanks for that  thesis Link... I am sure that is useful...

Comment: So, the question was "Given a morphism of stacks $B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$, when does the fibre product $B\mathcal{G}\times_{B\mathcal{H}}B\mathcal{G}$ a stack coming from Lie groupoid"... You have changed this question to "Given a morphism of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, when does the fibred product $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{H}}\mathcal{G}$ is  a Lie groupoid"... Then, you are saying if $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{H}}\mathcal{G}$ is a Lie groupoid, then $$B\mathcal{G}\times_{B\mathcal{H}}B\mathcal{G}\cong B(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{H}}\mathcal{G})$$.

Comment: You said "For the stack $BG\times_{BH} BG$ to be equivalent to one of the form $BK$ for some _topological_ group $K$, the topological groupoid I just described must be _transitive_"... This I am not very sure how to take this.. So, you are saying If this particular groupoid $G\times H\times G\rightrightarrows H$ is a transitive Lie groupoid, then, there exists a Lie group $K$ such that $B(G\times H\times G\rightrightarrows H)\cong BK$... Is there any way how to get this $K$?

Comment: I know (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301638/isotropy-group-of-a-lie-groupoid-is-a-lie-group) that Isotropy group $\mathcal{G}_x$ of any object $x\in \mathcal{G}_0$ is a Lie group.. So, I am guessing for a transitive Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ we have $B\mathcal{G}=B\mathcal{G}_x$ i.e., $\mathcal{G}$ is Morita equivalent to a Lie groupoid coming from Lie group $\mathcal{G}_x$... This is just my guess that $\mathcal{G}$ is Morita equivalent to $\mathcal{G}_x$... Is this correct? Is this what you are thinking when you said above thing or  am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: _You have changed this question to "Given a morphism of Lie groupoids ..._ <--- no, I only addressed the case when you have Lie groups $G$ and $H$ and a map of stacks $BG\to BH$. Every such map is isomorphic to one coming from a homomorphism $G\to H$. || _So, you are saying If this particular groupoid ...is a transitive Lie groupoid_ <-- Yes. || _Is there any way how to get this $K$_ <-- I described it in my answer. || _I am guessing for a transitive Lie groupoid.._ <-- almost: you also need $t\big|_{s^{-1}(x)} \colon s^{-1}(x) \to Obj(\mathcal{G})$ to be a submersion.

Comment: I am sorry if “you changed that question” sounded rude... I was thinking it was your strategy... Yes, you described $K$ in this particular case, I was thinking if there is any common technique to get such Lie group... I understand that $K$ you have explained.. “you also need $t:s^{-1}(x)\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ to be a submersion”... ok ok.. I am trying to find a proof of that result. Thank you.

Comment: _I am trying to find a proof of that result._ <-- it's the definition of a weak equivalence $X\to Y$ of Lie groupoids. See my paper http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/26/29/26-29abs.html especially the discussion in section 8

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that I understand your last comment completely.... I said, for transitive Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}$, we have that $\mathcal{G}_x$ is a Lie group and that $B\mathcal{G}=B\mathcal{G}_x$... Then you said "you also need $t:s^{-1}(x)\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ is a submersion" and asked me to look at your paper, section 8... I could not figure out what you are referring in that paper..

Comment: Are you saying for $B\mathcal{G}=B\mathcal{G}_x$, we need a **Morita equivalence of categories** $(\mathcal{G}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{G}_0)\rightarrow (\mathcal{G}_x\rightrightarrows *)$... A morphism of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is a Morita equivalence if 1)  $t\pi_1:\mathcal{G}_1\times_{\mathcal{G}_0}\mathcal{H}_0\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ is a surjective submersion 2) some other condition....

Comment: So, here we want $t\pi_1:\mathcal{G}_1\times_{\mathcal{G}_0}\mathcal{H}_0\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ i.e., $t\circ \pi_1:\mathcal{G}_1\times \mathcal{G}_0\rightarrow \mathcal{G}_0$ to be surjective submersion... (Orbifolds as groupoids, Moerdijk, page 5, subsection 2.4) This is what you are saying... Right? Do you want me to see anything else in that paper? I could not understand what you are referring to in your paper..  CAn you please confirm..

Comment: _Right?_ <--- yes. The stuff in section 8 of my paper relies on reading some definitions in previous sections, to see why Lie groupoids are an example :-) "Morita equivalence" here is a phrase with multiple definitions in this context, so I find it an unhelpful phrase. Better is "weak equivalence", since that refers to an actual functor. You **don't** want _a_ weak equivalence $(X_1\rightrightarrows X_0)\rightarrow (X_x\rightrightarrows *)$, since such a thing might not exist, but the inclusion functor $(X_x\rightrightarrows *) (X_1\rightrightarrows X_0)\rightarrow $ to be a weak equivalence.

Comment: Thansk for clarification :) I am ok with weak equivalence :) I directly jumped into section 8 and was confused.. I will read from beginning of the paper (1 page per day is my plan) and see if I can grasp something.... I also decided not to ask you more than one clarifications/suggestion/help per day...

Comment: I forgot to mention.. As you said, there is no obvious map $(X_1\rightrightarrows X_0)\rightarrow (X_x\rightrightarrows *)$ but there is this inclusion map $(X_x\rightrightarrows *)\rightarrow (X_1\rightrightarrows X_0)$ given by $g:x\rightarrow x$ mapping to $g$ and $*$ is mapping to $x\in X_0$... And you want **this** functor to be a weak equivalence.. If this holds then we are done but  I somehow think this is **too much to ask**.. I will figure out what is going on here...

Comment: By too much, I mean the following... For  stacks $B\mathcal{G}$ and $B\mathcal{G_x}$ to be isomorphic, we only need that $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{G}_x$ are Morita equivalent Lie groupoids (page $6$ of Moerdijk) i.e., it is sufficient if there exist some Lie geoupoid $\mathcal{H}$ with weak equivalence $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow (\mathcal{G}_x\rightrightarrows *)$.. Asking inlcusion functor to be weak equivalence seem to be more than sufficient here.. so, was mentioning that...

Comment: But any weak equivalence $\mathcal{H}\rightarrow (\mathcal{G}_x\rightrightarrows *)$ is an actual equivalence, since $H_0 \to \ast$ has a section. And in any case, we are supplied with the inclusion functor, which is more than one can say for the abstract general case.

Comment: Definitely reasonable thing to say... :) :)

Comment: One small/quick question... Given morphisms of Lie groupoids $\phi:\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{K}$ and $\psi:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{K}$ , under some condition, the $2$-fibre product $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H}$ is a Lie groupoid. In a particular case when $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{H}=(G\rightrightarrows *)$ and $\mathcal{K}=(H\rightrightarrows *)$ for Lie groups $G,H$, you have said above a situation when the fibre product $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H}$ is also a Lie group of the form $(K\rightrightarrows *)$..

Comment: Is this written some where?  In a paper or a book or something like that? It is not that I did not understand and wanting to see somewhere... I understand this... I can write down in detail here as an answer but as always it will be like I am writing for my self and it does not make any difference for others.. :D :D  My interest is, If this is written in a paper or something like that I am hoping I can  see more results like this in that source...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik no, it's not written in a book or paper that I know of, I just gave you an outline of a proof. You should fill in any details you feel are not obvious in your own private notes.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that now... There seem to be slight difference in source/target maps of Lie groupoid  $G\times H\times G\rightarrow H$ for what you said and what I got... I see $s:G\times H\times G\rightarrow H$ is given by $(g_1,h,g_2)\mapsto h\cdot \theta(g_1)$ and $t:G\times H\times G\rightarrow H$ is given by $(g_1,h,g_2)\mapsto \theta(g_2)\cdot h$...  I do not think it makes so much difference... The next thing  I will ask is when this Lie groupoid is transitive.. I think I might end up with same conlcusion as you...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I may have written down an isomorphic groupoid :-)

Comment: One small (last) question... Even though maps are different, I got same result. $\theta: G\rightarrow H$ is surjective iff Lie groupoid is transitive.Transitive Lie groupoid is weak equvalent to isotropy group..So, I should just pick some random $h\in H$ and see what is its $\mathcal{G}_h$... Here also I got same thing.. Istropy group is $G\times_HG$... It is ok till here...

Comment: As isotrpy group is a Lie group, this (after identification) is a Lie subgroup of $G\times H\times G$ which does not say if $G\times_H G$ is Lie subgroup of $G\times G$... but, why do we need that?  I do not know what I am missing... All you want is a Lie group and $G\times_H G$ is a Lie group (not necessarily Lie subgroup of $G\times G$).. It will be good if it is a Lie subgroup of $G\times G$ but why do we even need that? I do not know what I am misunderstanding..

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik sorry, but not now.

Comment: :) :) No  No... I do not expect you to reply immediately.... I will just leave comment here.. Please see only when you are super free.... That chat thing I pressed only because it is saying again and again to move to chat... I will write here only :) :) No problem at all... Please carry on with your work and see when you are free :)

Comment: In short, my question is the following : Why do we bother about this $G\times_H G$ **being Lie subgroup of** $G\times G$?? There is already a Lie group structure on $G\times_H G$, just like any Isotropy group of Lie groupoid... (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301638/isotropy-group-of-a-lie-groupoid-is-a-lie-group).. If the question is not sensible, I am explaining below more carefully...

Comment: What I am trying to understand here is... given a morphism of Lie groups $G\rightarrow H$, which gives a morphism of Lie groupoids $F:(G\rightrightarrows *)\rightarrow (H\rightrightarrows *)$, what is the $2$-fibre product of $F$ with itself i.e., what is $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{H}}\mathcal{G}$??  I understand that the groupoid $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{H}}\mathcal{G}$ is $G\times H\times G\rightrightarrows H$ where source map is $s(g_1,h,g_2)=h\cdot\theta(g_1)$ and target map is $t(g_1,h,g_2)=\theta(g_2)\cdot h$.

Comment: I want to see when this Lie groupoid is transitive Lie groupoid so that I can then say this Lie groupoid is  weakly equivalent to a Lie groupoid of the form $(K\rightrightarrows *)$ for some Lie group $K$, more precisely this $K$ is the isotropy group of some object of $(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{H}}\mathcal{G})$. I then see that $\theta$ is surjective then Lie groupoid is transitive and if it is transitive then $\theta$ is surjective.

Comment: Assuming $\theta$ is surjective, I want to see what is the isotropy group. I see that isotropy group $(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{H}}\mathcal{G})_h=G\times_H G$.   What I do not understand is, why do we bother about this $G\times_H G$ **being Lie subgroup of** $G\times G$??

Comment: It's irrelevant, it was just a comment.

Comment: Oh.. :) I was banging my head to wall to understand why it is relevant... This is my last comment for today as I promised... I will ask some question tomorrow... :) Please leave a message when you are free (anytime today or tomorrow) for five minutes...

Answer (score 3):

Pullbacks of stacks coming from Lie groupoids are not always equivalent to Lie groupoids.

Take $G=H=\mathbb{R}$.  Define $F(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$ and $F(x)=exp(−1/x^2)$ if $x>0$.

The pullback is not equivalent to a Lie groupoid in this situation:
the set-theoretical pullback is $(−\infty,0]\times(−\infty,0]\cup \{(x,x)|x\in \mathbb{R}\}$,
which is clearly not a smooth manifold.

One can guarantee that the pullback is a Lie groupoid by imposing transversality
conditions on the maps involved.
That is, $A \times_C B$ is a Lie groupoid if $A_0 \rightarrow C_0 \leftarrow B_0$ is transversal
and $A_1 \rightarrow  C_1 \leftarrow B_1$ is transversal,
where subscripts $0$ and $1$ denotes objects and morphisms respectively.
(In fact, this transversality condition guarantees that the pullback
is also a homotopy pullback, which is almost always what one actually wants.)

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by "Your first claim"... All you are saying is that pullback of a smooth map $G\rightarrow H$ is not a manifold... Are you saying something else also... I understand that given a smooth map $G\rightarrow H$, the pullback $G\times_HG$ is not necessarily a manifold... I am looking for a criterion on $G\rightarrow H$ and also on $BG\rightarrow BH$ so that $G\times_HG$ is a Lie group $K$ and $BG\times_{BH}BG$ is the space $BK$...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: You have two sentences marked with a question mark.  The "first claim" refers to the first of these two questions.  So it is false that the pullback is a Lie groupoid.

Comment: So, you are saying for $F:B\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{H}$ be a morphism of stacks the fibered product $B\mathcal{G}\times_{B\mathcal{H}}B\mathcal{G}$ is not necessarily of the form $B\mathcal{K}$ for some Lie groupoid $\mathcal{K}$..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Yes, in the example that I gave the pullback is not a Lie groupoid.

Comment: You want me to treat Lie group $G$ as a Lie groupoid.. that’s fine.. I am looking for a positive result in some special case.. I am aware that pullback need not be manifold.. Is it clear what I am trying to ask? My English is not good so I don’t know if it conveyed correctly.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: There are no Lie groups in my answer.  G and H are smooth manifolds, hence also Lie groupoids.  I simply reused the notation from the first part of your question.  If you need a positive result for some special case (which is not what your original question asks for), you can always demand transversality of the involved maps, which guarantees that the pullback is a Lie groupoid.

Comment: Oh no, I do not know why I said they are Lie groups.. for me $G,H$ means Lie groups... ok ok.. I would not have got confused if it was $M$ and $N$.. :) You are treating smooth manifolds as Lie groupoids.. that is fine.. I think I did not ask the question clearly.. With your permission, I would like to delete this question and ask a better one...this as it is seems to be not useful for anyone..

Comment: Not every Lie groupoid is of the form of manifold.. what can be said about General Lie groupoid. You are referring to Lie groupoids coming from a manifold,.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I answered the new version with arbitrary Lie groupoids.  I do not use MathJax because I need to retain the ability to copy-paste my texts.

Comment: What is transversal intersection in arbitrary lie groupoids? I know what is it in case of manifolds maps but not in case of morphism of Lie groupoids...You still have that code even when some one edits it. Why not leave it like that..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: The second paragraph in my answer explains carefully what transversality for Lie groupoids means: the object maps must be transversal and the morphism maps must be transversal (as maps of smooth manifolds).

Comment: I think I have to take a break.. i am one even able to see what is written there.. apologies.. can you please delete your answer so that I can delete this question..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: This is a legitimate question about pullbacks of Lie groupoids with a legitimate answer.  Deleting it goes against the policies of this site.  Even if it was deleted, it would be pretty soon undeleted because there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer.. I unaccepted the answer as the case of Lie groups is still not clear...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: The case of Lie groups is a special case of the criterion given in the answer: the object maps are *←*→*, which is transversal, so you only have to ask that the morphisms of Lie groups are transversal.

Comment: That is true, I was slightly confused... I realised it late... You are saying that, if I have morphism of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{K},\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{K}$ intersect transversally as you said, then the fibre product $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H}$ is a Lie groupoid.. This is ok at the level of Lie groupoids.. Is there any way to see this at the level of stacks.. Is there a quick  proof that in case Lie groupoids intersecting transversally then $B\mathcal{G}\times_{B\mathcal{K}}B\mathcal{H}\cong B(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H})$??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Transversal limits of Lie groupoids are also homotopy limits, and the Yoneda embedding preserves homotopy limits.  In particular, the image of a  transversal pullback square of Lie groupoids is a homotopy pullback square of stacks in groupoids.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not yet comfortable with notion of Transversal limits of Lie groupoids and homotopy limits.. I am guessing by Transversal limit you mean the pull back groupoid of Lie groupoids intersecting Transversally.. Is that correct? I do not understand at all when you say "In particular, the image of a transversal pullback square of Lie groupoids is a homotopy pullback square of stacks in groupoids" Pardon me for my dumbness.. Please explain little more..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Transversal pullbacks are defined in my answer.  A pullback that is transversal is automatically also a homotopy pullback.  The Yoneda embedding (denoted B in your posts) preserves homotopy limits, in particular, homotopy pullbacks.  Thus, applying B to a transversal pullback square of Lie groupoids produces a homotopy pullback square of stacks, which is precisely what you asked for in you second-to-the-last comment above (BG×BKBH≅B(G×KH)).

Comment: I got confused because you are saying Transversal limit.. By your above comment it is clear that you mean Transversal pullback which is defined in answer... please suggest some place to read about homotopy limits and the result that Yoneda embedding preserves homotopy limits... I am new to this so do not know why Yoneda embedding preserves homotopy limits I.e., why $B\mathcal{G}\times_{B\mathcal{K}}B\mathcal{H}=B(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H})$ please suggest a reference..  apologies for many questions.. could not find it on searching online..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: All pullbacks are limits.  A good list of references for homotopy limits is available on the nLab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+limit.  Preservation of limits by the Yoneda embedding is discussed here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+lemma+for+%28infinity%2C1%29-categories

Comment: Thank you, I will read that.