# Yoneda Embedding and pull back

Tags: ct.category-theory, stacks, limits-and-colimits, lie-groupoids

- Given a manifold $M$ we have a geometric stack associated to it namely $\underline{M}$ whose objects are smooth maps to $M$. For the sake of consistency I am writing $BM$ for $\underline{M}$.
- Given a Lie group $G$ we have a geometric stack associated to it namely $BG$ whose objects are principal $G$ bundles.
- Given a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ we have a geometric stack associated to it namely $B\mathcal{G}$ whose objects are principal $\mathcal{G}$ bundles.

These are called as Yoneda embedddings (I do not have precise reference where it is called so, except for manifolds [corollary $4.16$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.4160.pdf)).

Given a smooth map $f:M\rightarrow N$, **if it is a submersion**, then, $M\times_NM$ is a manifold. We have $2$-fibre product $\underline{M}\times_{\underline{N}}\underline{N}$ and the stack $\underline{M\times_NM}$.

I am able to see  that $\underline{M\times_NM}\cong \underline{M}\times_{\underline{N}}\underline{M}$.  We have $B(M\times_NM)\cong BM\times_{BN}BN$.

David Roberts say [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/321296/118688)  that same holds in case of Lie groups and Dimitri Pavlov say  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/320239/118688)  that same holds for Lie groupoids i.e., we have following.

- Given a morphism of Lie groups $\theta:G\rightarrow H$ **which is a surjective submersion** (submersion is to ensure $G\times_H G$ is a Lie group), then $$B(G\times_HG)\cong BG\times_{BH}BG.$$
- Given a morphism of Lie groupoids $f:\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ such  that  the [fibered product](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203100.pdf)  (in page no $5$, section $2.3$)  $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{H}}\mathcal{G}$ is a Lie groupoid, then $$B(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{H}}\mathcal{G})\cong B\mathcal{G}\times_{B\mathcal{H}}B\mathcal{G}$$

Dmitri Pavlov said [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320210/fibered-product-of-stacks-comes-from-a-lie-groupoid) that this has something to do with **Preservation of limits by the Yoneda embedding** and suggested [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+lemma+for+%28infinity%2C1%29-categories) and [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+limit). But I am not familiar with $(\infty,1)$ categories. So, I am asking here (I am asking as a separate question).

> How does one see that Yoneda embedding preserves limits in this setup? Please see my answer, I see the case in classical category theory.

Just an outline is also ok, just that it would be good if it is not mixed with $(\infty,1)$ categories.

Comment: They are not quite Yoneda embeddings: Yoneda is for **pre**sheaves. The 2-functor $LieGroupoids \to DiffStacks$ is not a full embedding, since not all maps between stacks come (even up to isomorphism) from functors between Lie groupoids. What you describe is the composite of $LieGroupoids \to Gpd^{Mfld^{op}}$, the 2-categorical Yoneda embedding, and stackification $Gpd^{Mfld^{op}} \to Stack(Mfld)$, and happens to factor through $DiffStacks \subset Stack(Mfld)$.

Comment: Also, Yoneda preserves limits, and so does stackification, up to equivalence. Limits here should be suitably 2-categorical. And, in fact, what is usually referred to as the weak or homotopy pullback is in this setting the comma object (which coincides with the isocomma object as all 2-arrows in this setting are invertible). Because manifolds give representable presheaves, and the open cover topology is subcanonical, representable presheaves are sheaves and hence stacks, so the 2-functor $Mfld \to DiffStacks$ really is the Yoneda embedding: manifolds form a full subcategory of $DiffStacks$.

Comment: _Given a morphism of Lie groups $\theta\colon G\to H$ which is a submersion_ <-- no, when $\theta$ is a **surjective** submersion. When you say "it turns out", you should link to your source for this to aid other people who are learning, and so that people can check your assertion. :-) \\ _Given a morphism of Lie groupoids $f\colon \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{H}$ that intersects transversally_ <-- this is meaningless, what does it mean for a single morphism to "intersect transversally"? Section 2.3 of the notes of Moerdijk to which you link never uses the word "transversal[ly]".

Comment: I will respond one by one comment.. i  understand “The $2$-functor $\text{Lie Groupoids}\rightarrow \text{Differentiable stack}$ is not a full embedding since not al maps between stacks come from functor between Lie groupoids”. I do not understand what is written after that... I will try to read what is $2$-categorical Yoneda embedding... Can you please tell what is $\text{Gpd}^{\text{Mfld}^{\text{op}}}$ @DavidRoberts this is for your first comment..

Comment: All that said, I have a paper in preparation that proves that certain localisations of 2-categories at a class of fully faithful morphisms (of which $LieGroupoids \to DiffStacks$ is an example) preserve PIE limits.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_category#Definition

Comment: For your third comment @DavidRoberts I have added source for both and changed it to surjective submersion... I did not say the word transversal intersection. Dimitri Pavlov said it, he said it for two functor intersect transversely, by one functor intersecting transversally I mean it intersect with itself transversally.. yes, Moerdijk does not use the word , instead he give condition when fibered product is a Lie groupoid,,  I should simply remove that word and say what it is,, I will edit it..

Comment: I should not have asked what is $\text{Gpd}^{\text{Mfld}^{op}}$.. I should have guessed it... they are functors $\text{Mfld}^{\text{op}}\rightarrow \text{Gpd}$...  given Lie gorhpoid $\mathcal{G}$ we have a functor $B\mathcal{G}:\text{Mfld}^{\text{op}}\rightarrow \text{Gpd}$ given by $U\mapsto B\mathcal{G}(U)$ this is contravariant so you have written $\text{op}$.. @DavidRoberts this is for your functor category comment

Comment: @DavidRoberts can I get to see that paper (if you think I can understand something)..

Comment: Given a category fibered in groupoids over the category of manifolds equivalently a functor $\text{Mfld}^{op}\rightarrow \text{Gpd}$ there is the notion of stackification https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02ZM which associated a stackk over the category of manifolds.. That is what you are saying when you write $\text{Gpd}^{\text{Mfld}^{\text{op}}}\rightarrow \text{Stack}/\text{Mfld}$... I am trying to see why this should factor through $\text{Diff.Stacks}\subseteq \text{Stack}(Mfld)$ @DavidRoberts

Comment: @DavidRoberts Please consider giving reference where I can understand "Also, Yoneda preserves limits, and so does stackification, up to equivalence. Limits here should be suitably 2-categorical. And, in fact, what is usually referred to as the weak or homotopy pullback is in this setting the comma object (which coincides with the isocomma object as all 2-arrows in this setting are invertible)." There is a notion of $2$-Yoneda lemma in page 23 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.4160.pdf which I do not if related to 2-categorical YOneda embedding that you are talking about..

Comment: These are questions that I think you need to take to math.stackexchange. But as a hint: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04Y1

Comment: I am reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07973.pdf in particular page no 7 and 8. I think I can get something, I will try to understand what you said..

Comment: _(so that $G\times_H G$ is a Lie group)_ <--no, you need the submersion so that this is a Lie group, you need the surjectivity so that you have the equivalence of stacks.

Comment: _given Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ we have a functor_ <-- well, first you have a functor $y(\mathcal{G}) = LieGroupoids(-,\mathcal{G})$, which is what you should be referring to. || _I am trying to see why this should factor through_ it doesn't, but the composite with the Yoneda embedding does, literally by definition, as the full sub-2-category containing the image of $LieGroupoids$ inside $Stacks(Mfld)$ _is_ the 2-category of differentiable stacks.

Comment: Thanks for stacks project link.. I did not even know hoe to search there.. initially I have written submersion and with that I have written so that $G\times_HG$ is a Lie group.. I changed it to surjective submersion but did not change the Lie group oart

Comment: I'm done for now.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I deleted my comments from Jan 23, 1:28 AM.. They are more like self notes.. There was no response from any user.. So, deleted them... Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an arbitrary category $C$, if a functor $F: I\to C$ has a limit $L$ with projections $\pi_i, i\in \mathrm{Ob}(I)$, then we have a natural (in $X$) isomorphism in $\hom_C(X, L)\to \lim_i\hom_C(X,F(i))$.

In fact, this is better stated as : $(\pi_i\circ - :  \hom_C(X,L)\to \hom_C(X, F(i)))_i$ is a limite cone.

Now if $I$ is small, $\mathbf{Set}^I$ makes sense, and limits in this category are computed pointwise, so that $(\pi_i\circ - :  \hom_C(-,L)\to \hom_C(-, F(i)))_i$ is a limit cone in $\mathbf{Set}^I$ (a limit cone of functors).

What this says, with less precision on which maps we use, is $\hom_C(-,\lim F) \simeq \lim_i\hom_C(-,F(i))$.

But the Yoneda embedding is precisely $y : A\mapsto \hom_C(-,A)$, $f\mapsto f\circ -$ (for it to make sense as a functor we have to make sense of $\mathbf{Set}^C$, which can be problematic if $C$ isn't small, but let's not think about that), so what we said above can be restated : $y$ sends limit cones to limit cones, or again with less precision on the maps $y(\lim F) \simeq \lim y\circ F$, which is exactly the definition of preserving limits.

Now to prove the claim about the limit cone : let $(A,(p_i))$ be any cone over $i\mapsto \hom_C(X,F(i))$ in $\mathbf{Set}$. Fix $a\in A$. Then $(p_i(a))_i$ is a family of maps, and since $(p_i)$ is a cone, for each $f:i\to j$ it satisfies $\hom_C(X,F(f))(p_i(a)) = p_j(a)$, so $F(f)\circ p_i(a) = p_j(a)$.

[image]

Thus $(p_i(a))_i$ is actually a cone over $F$ with domain $X$; so it factors uniquely through some $p(a) : X\to L$, we then have $\pi_i\circ p(a) = p_i(a)$, in other words $(\pi_i\circ -)(p(a)) = p_i(a)$.

Define $p:A\to \hom_C(X,L)$ this way, and then the above equation tells us $(\pi_i\circ -)\circ p = p_i$, which tells us exactly that our initial cone factors through the intended one. It's not hard to check that this factorization is unique; so it is indeed a limit cone.

As stated, this has nothing to do with homotopy limits and $(\infty, 1)$-categories, though.

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if I got it correctly... Thank you... This only says about $M\mapsto \underline{M}$ which is of the form $\text{Hom}(-,M)$.. Can you please say aomthing about $\mathcal{G}\mapsto B\mathcal{G}$.. How to (Do we) see them as $\text{Hom}(-,\mathcal{G})$? Can what you have written be extended for Lie groups?

Comment: Yes you got it correctly; I don't know about $B\mathcal{G}$ though, I don't know what it is

Comment: Thank you Max. Are you familiar with what is called Homotopy limit?

Answer (score 0):

Let $F:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is a functor. This is also called as diagram indexed by $\mathcal{I}$.

By the Limit of this diagram, we mean an object (universal ) 
$L$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and a collection of arrows (universal again) $\pi_i:L\rightarrow F(i)$ such that, for each arrow $m:i\rightarrow j$ in $\mathcal{I} $ the following diagram is commutative.
This is usually denoted by $\varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}}F(i)$ or simply by $\varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}}F$.

[image]

Fixing an object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$,
I want to prove that 
$$\varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}}(\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,F(i)))
=\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,\varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}}F(i))$$
i.e., an isomorphism 
$$\varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}}(\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,F(i)))
=\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,L)$$ Let $(A,(p_i))$ be cone for the functor $\mathcal{I}\rightarrow \text{Set}$ given by $i\mapsto \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,F(i))$ i.e., we have following commutative diagrams

[image]

To prove that $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,L)$ is equal to $\varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}}(\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,F(i)))$ it suffices to prove that there exists unique arrow $p:A\rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,L)$ such that the following diagram is commutative.

[image]

So, we define an arrow $p:A\rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,L)$ i.e., given $a\in A$ we define  arrow $p(a):X\rightarrow L$ in $\mathcal{C}$. How to one get such arrow? See above diagram.

For each $a\in A$, we have $p_i(a):X\rightarrow F(i)$ such that $F(m)\circ p_i(a)=p_j(a)$ giving following diagram which gives an arrow $X\rightarrow L$ by universal property

[image]

This is the $p(a):X\rightarrow L$ that we associate for each $a\in L$.

This gives the map $p:A\rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,L)$ satisfying conditions mentioned above. Thus, we have 
$$\varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}}(\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,F(i)))
=\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,L)=\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,\varprojlim_{\mathcal{I}}F(i))$$

Consider the functor $\text{Man}\rightarrow \text{Stacks}$ that sends $M$ to $\underline{M}$ which is precisely $\text{Hom}(-,M)$.

Let $M_1,M_2,M_3$ be manifolds and $M_1\rightarrow M_2,M_3\rightarrow M_2$ be arrows.

We have $\varprojlim M_i = M_1\times_{M_2}M_3$. We have $$\text{Hom}(-,\varprojlim M_i)=\varprojlim \text{Hom}(-,M_i)$$
$$\underline{M_1\times_{M_2}M_3}=\text{Hom}(-,M_1\times_{M_2}M_3)=\varprojlim \underline{M_i}=\underline{M_1}\times_{\underline{M_2}}\underline{M_3}$$

Comment: This still does not answer the question of Lie groupoids.. I am trying to make sense of how $\mathcal{G}\rightarrow B\mathcal{G}$ is said as Yoneda embeddding... This does not seem to be of the form $Hom(-,\mathcal{G})$ wherever this makes sense..